# When pod dies, what happens to secrets Hashicorp Vault

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I am running Hashicorp’s Vault server as a docker image as one of the pods in a Kubernetes cluster.
I have defined service too.
What will happen to the secret that are stored, if that pod dies.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the storage you used for vault. Vault supports various storage (see [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/index.html)). For example,

- If you are using `In-Memory` storage, then data will be vanished after pod dies.
- If you are using `Filesystem`, then it will depend on type of volume you use (see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) for different types of volumes). For `emptyDir` volume data will be lost after pod dies.
- For other storage type like `Google Cloud Storage`, `Amazon S3` data will remain even if pod dies. But if you delete the storage data will be gone.

Comment: The point I wanted to know is, For the first pod, a Root token was generated and using that token we first login using the command " vault login TOKEN-XXXXXXXXXXX " then mount those storage.

When a new pod spins up, A new Root token is generated, Then how can that new token can decrypt or 3 unseal keys can decrypt secret which was stored using older tokens.

Comment: **vault dependent on storage**. All secret are stored in the storage you defined. Vault keeps data encrypted. So, vault needs the encryption key in order to decrypt the data. This encryption key is also stored in the storage but encrypted by another key called master key. I think you are familiar with seal and unseal. When vault is in seal state it' useless because it has no master key. So when we unseal vault with unseal keys, it generates the master key using these unseal key(using shamir's secret sharing algorithm). By this master key it can now get the encryption key and decrypt the data.

Answer (score 0):

The secrets are stored in the storage backend. The most common storage backend is consul and the secrets remain in the pvc (persistent volume claim). If the vault pod dies and it spins up again, as long as the consul pvc are intact - the secrets would remain.